# Проблема понимания цикла. Python

Tags: python

Почему при очистке tmp, он удаляется и в result? В result должны быть списки подстрок без повторяющихся символов.

```
def lengthOfLongestSubstring(s):
    tmp = []
    result = []
    index = 0
    for i in s:
        if i not in tmp:
           tmp.append(i)
           continue
        result.append(tmp)
        tmp.clear()
    return result
print(lengthOfLongestSubstring('pwwkew'))
```

Comment: ничего не понятно. Что должно быть на выходе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что не нужно использовать метод `tmp.clear()` не понимая чётко что вы делаете. Используйте вместо этого `tmp = []` как и в коде выше.

`result.append(tmp)` добавляет **ссылку** на `tmp`, и когда вы пишете `tmp.clear()`, то происходит то, что вы видите - очищаются все добавленные списки, потому что вы добавили в `result` много копий **одного и того же списка**. А когда вы пишете `tmp = []`, вы создаёте **новый** пустой список, не зависимый от других списков.